# imagejpeg doesn't work properly

Tags: php, image

php doesn't work properly on my site.

if I write

```
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("./image.jpg");
```

it works properly,
if I write

```
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://mysite/image.jpg");
```

it doesn't get image..

can anyone help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg()  function work with BASE PATH(Directory path) not with URL (http:// is url not base path)

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the [`allow_url_fopen` configuration setting](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is set to `true` in `php.ini`.
- Check that the URL is correct and the image can be fetched via this URL.

Comment: Thank you.. 

there was "allow_url_fopen" set on Off.. 
Changing it to On works 100%.. Thanks